# Server's public key usage in DH key exchange algorithm

Tags: c++, sockets, security, networking, openssl

In TLS when the RSA algorithm is used for key exchange, the client uses the public key from the server's certificate to encrypt the pre-master secret key and sends the result to the server. Is the server's public key used to encrypt something when the DH algorithm is used for key exchange?

Comment: @GaborLengyel Right. But for which data server's public key used for encryption in DH key exchange algorithm?

Comment: The answer is no. In RSA-authenticated ephemeral DH (including ephemeral elliptic curve) RSA is only used to *sign* handshake messages.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I just don't understand how in that case the client checks the authenticity of the certificate? When RSA is used for key exchange, everything is clear to me. This algorithm requires the use of the server's public key to encrypt the pre-master secret, which prevents the server's certificate from being tampered with or used by someone else. However, it is not clear to me how you can check the server certificate without using the server's public key (as I understand it, this is exactly what happens in the case of DH)

Comment: The checking of the server *certificate* is done identically in either case, and is not done the way you're alluding to. This is a tutorial-level question about TLS and is  best answered by reading one of the numerous tutorials available elsewhere on the net.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I had read. The server sends a certificate signed by a certification authority. The client calculate the checksum from the data, and also decrypts the signature of the certification authority. If these checksums match, then the check is considered passed. But if the man in the middle uses my server's certificate without any changes, then such a check will also be passed. How to determine that we are interacting with a man in the middle on client-side?

Comment: DH is used *only* for key exchange. It is not used for authenticity and the DH public key does not appear in the server certificate. The server certificate contains the public key for an algorithm used for signing, such as RSA, DSA or ECDSA. A ServerKeyExchange message is sent from the server to the client to pass the DH public key (this value is ephemeral). So, for example, you might use RSA for authentication and DH for key exchange.

Comment: @MattCaswell OK. The certificate is needed for authentication, so that the client would be convinced that it is interacting with the correct server. If the person in the middle copies this certificate to themselves and sends it to the client, how will the client understand that the attacker sent the certificate?

Comment: The details vary by TLS version, but in TLSv1.3 the server sends  a CertificateVerify message to the client which is signed using the server's private key. The client verifies the signature with the public key from the server's certificate. Since an attacker who just copies someone else's certificate does not have the private key they cannot create valid signatures.